# WebSocket connection failure over Letsencrypt SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, websocket, tornado, lets-encrypt

Hey guys I was using python tornado websocket along with angular-websocket on the client on nginx server over letsencrypt certificate. After the last renewal of the ssl certificate, the websocket is unable to create a connection with the error

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://myDomain.com:9999/xyz' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled

My nginx is configured with

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/run/gunicorn.sock;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}


listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myDomain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myDomain.com/privkey.pem;
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
```

Do I need to make any changes in the nginx config?
P.S. - I've tried creating another certificate, it still doesn't work.

Comment: The link should be `wss://myDomain.com/xyz` and not `wss://myDomain.com:9999/xyz` I believe, because SSL would be running on 443?

Answer (score -1):

**Update with the solution:** It was the permission issues of the letsencrypt files.

Comment: Can you expound, how did you address the permission issues?

Comment: @Trevor you can simply change the file permission to 775 or 755.